# Jquery mobile animation not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile alpha 4. I simply bind a click event on a span tag with matching id like:

```
function bindwChk() {

    $j(".wchk").bind('click', function (event) {
        // unbind this event first so that the user cannot click again on word while
        // current event is in progress
        $j(".wchk").unbind('click')

        if (!$j("#wchkdiv")[0]) {
            $j("#misc-cntr").append('<div id="wchkdiv" data-rel="dialog" > </div>');
            $j("#wchkdiv").dialog();


        }

$j('#wchkdiv').html($j("#d1").html());

$j.mobile.changePage($('#wchkdiv'), { transition: "slideup"});

return false;

    });
}
```

When I click on the word the dialog transition animation displays for a small fraction of a second but after that page is blank white space and the dialog seems to be invisible.

Any one knows the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem got fixed after I removed the

```
<div data-role="page">
```

from the dialog markup. For some reasons, the `data-role=page` in the dialog would make the dialog invisible.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon, does that fix it?

```
$j(".wchk").unbind('click');
```

**edit**: oops I didn't see your last line about the actual problem which this would not effect. Well you are just calling `dialog()` without any `animation` parameters, I will try to find something.